# Webpack: “there are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing” but modules referenced are identical" but i can't find the typo

Tags: reactjs, webpack

i am working with React and get these errors that i found others saying were due to a typo. but i cannot find the source - the typo. it is a cryptic error. i have tried opening the files it lists, but they are all files that are inside `node_modules` - not files i have coded.

what am i missing?

`webpackHotDevClient.js:138 C:/Users/benja/Documents/Udacity/Project-7/react-map/node_modules/object-assign/index.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\benja\Documents\Udacity\Project-7\react-map\node_modules\object-assign\index.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\benja\Documents\Udacity\Project-7\react-map\node_modules\react-scripts\config\polyfills.js
* C:\Users\benja\documents\udacity\project-7\react-map\node_modules\object-assign\index.js
    Used by 3 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\benja\documents\udacity\project-7\react-map\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js
printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:138
handleWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:155
./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:208
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/eventtarget.js.EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:51
(anonymous) @ main.js:278
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/main.js.SockJS._transportMessage @ main.js:276
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/emitter.js.EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:50
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ websocket.js:35
webpackHotDevClient.js:138 (webpack)/buildin/global.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\benja\Documents\Udacity\Project-7\react-map\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
    Used by 23 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\benja\Documents\Udacity\Project-7\react-map\node_modules\sockjs-client\lib\entry.js
* C:\Users\benja\documents\udacity\project-7\react-map\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\benja\documents\udacity\project-7\react-map\node_modules\symbol-observable\es\index.js
printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:138
handleWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:155
./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:208
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/eventtarget.js.EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:51
(anonymous) @ main.js:278
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/main.js.SockJS._transportMessage @ main.js:276
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/emitter.js.EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:50
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ websocket.js:35
webpackHotDevClient.js:138 (webpack)/buildin/module.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\benja\Documents\Udacity\Project-7\react-map\node_modules\webpack\buildin\module.js
    Used by 3 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\benja\Documents\Udacity\Project-7\react-map\node_modules\node-libs-browser\node_modules\punycode\punycode.js
* C:\Users\benja\documents\udacity\project-7\react-map\node_modules\webpack\buildin\module.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\benja\documents\udacity\project-7\react-map\node_modules\lodash\isBuffer.js`

Comment: Try `rm -rf node_modules/ && npm i && npm start`

Comment: what will that do? i have just recently started git and haven't used `rm`.

Comment: The command reinstall `node_modules` and restart the project

Comment: i tried it, and nothing changed.